# Express.js: undefined request.body

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios, fetch

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors());

app.post('/', (req,res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send('received')
})

app.listen(5000, console.log('Server is running on port 5000'));
```

I am trying to send data to the back-end but always getting undefined

[image]

I tried to you a parser but seems like just wrapping void into an object

[image]

Comment: In the second image in postman you need to change the type dropdown from text to JSON, express.json() only parses the body when the header Content-type is set to "application/json" and changing that dropdown will automatically include that header.

Here the docs if it helps explain why you get empty object in second image https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.json

Comment: btw, the json your posting is invalid, JSON !== Object literal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting as answer from my comment.

In the second image in postman you need to change the type dropdown from text to JSON, express.json() only parses the body when the header Content-type is set to "application/JSON" and changing that dropdown will automatically include that header.

Here are the [docs](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.json) if it helps explain why you get the empty object in the second image